# oauth access token from SAML response?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have one demo application ,it configured SAML2.0 SSO with the WSO2 Identity Server.and also its working fine.Now i want to get oauth token from the SAML response.Is it possible to parse oauth token from the SAML response ,any sugession ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. it is supported. You can send a SAML Assertion to the /token endpoint and receive a access token.  Identity Server supports for `SAML 2.0 Bearer Assertion Profiles` and [This](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-saml2-bearer-15) has been implemented. Here you want to do a POST to the /token end point with Base64 url encoded SAML assertion. You can find more details from [here] [1](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/31/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile-for-oauth-2-0/).  POST request would like following

> curl -X POST -u "QlthIzYUOK5DS0BXW8Cy8uFJjKAa:XFfgPmTbMaQ5eScc0rSnAW9ZIgwa" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -d "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer&assertion=PHNhbWxwOl...[omitted for brevity]...ZT4" https://{host}:{port}/oauth2/token

Comment: {"error":"server_error","error_description":"Error when issuing the access token"}

Comment: in IS console getting following error  :  
[Fatal Error] :1:213: Element type "saml2:Assertion" must be followed by either
attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
[2014-02-26 11:59:14,294] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.
grant.saml.SAML2BearerGrantHandler} -  Error in constructing XML Object from the
 encoded String

Comment: Yes.. there may be issue with the SAML Assertion that you have send..  Could please verify it...  further you can enable the debug logs in OAuth component and see.. http://soasecurity.org/2014/02/26/how-to-wso2is-troubleshooting-wso2-identity-server-1/

Comment: Enabled the DEBUG logs as you said, Following is the last part of DEBUG logs before the error:
[2014-02-26 17:26:03,221] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.
grant.saml.SAML2BearerGrantHandler} -  Received SAML assertion : <saml2:Assertio
n ID="bejaenngkdpdjdgbnkkmgpkbpnlgdpioldbmglbl" IssueInstant="2014-02-26T11:54:0
5.376Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:
xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"¤?n++[[?n++n++\n++n++Y\n++?n++_¢X]¤Hn++\n++
n++n++n++\n++\+¢n++[Y\+¥?+ön++SS?n++n++n++?n++n++[YZY?Yn++_¢X]?n++[n++?]?Hn++n++

Comment: So there is issue with the SAML Assertion that you have send..  you need to make sure... it is correctly  Base64 encoded..  and then url encoded. I guess,  It is better to verify it again

Comment: You may be sending the <SAMLResponse> not the <SAMLAssertion>.  please refer more details about  SAML2 OAuth profile with WSO2IS from here http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/31/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile-for-oauth-2-0/

Comment: It says  "cannot be cast to org.opensaml.saml2.core.Assertion "  so object created from your input is not a SAML2 Assertion