# Oauth2.0 : how to use WSO2 API Manager with other WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: authentication, oauth, wso2

I would like to use WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Identity Server together.

WSO2 API Manager:  ip:  `192_168_0_1`

WSO2 Identity Server:  ip:  `192_168_0_2`

There are some ref:
[WSO2 - Identity Server and API Manager working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430211/wso2-identity-server-and-api-manager-working-together)

[oAuth2 - WSO2 API Manager and Identity Server Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23007006/oauth2-wso2-api-manager-and-identity-server-integration)

I want to use WSO2 API Manager as a getway, to use Identity Server for Oauth2.0. so I  modify AM's identity.xml and api-manager.xml to change some important urls to point to IS,  but it's not working.

Also, I installed a feature of "key manager" in IS according to a [message](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@wso2.org/msg23644.html).
When I sub an application in `//192_168_0_1:9443/store`, click the "Generate" button, it's `Error: "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey"`

```
[2014-04-23 13:35:47,455] ERROR - APIStoreHostObject Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:22
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getApplicationAccessToken
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.getApplicationAccessToken(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:775)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.getApplicationAccessKey(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:77)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:283)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c4._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:30)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c4.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_8(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:29)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:139)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:3)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-04-23 13:35:47,482] ERROR - subscription-add:jag org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:22
```

How can I use AM and IS together?  How can I configure that making AM to Oauth to another IS?

Comment: did you solve this issue? what was the solution? I also face same issue

Comment: were you bale to sort out this issue? what was the root cause? can you post the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have to enable the admin services of the identity Server so that the AM can use a WS of the IS to validate the access token:

Accessibility of this service is by default disabled. You need to go to Identity_Server_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml and set the value false on following element as follows:

```
<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
```

Also u have to insert a custom handler in the API manager through the GUI, section Main -> ESB -> Source View, this because the default handler tries to validate the access token internally in the key manager of the API manager.

U can find the procedure here https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Writing+a+Custom+Authentication+Handler

Comment: can you show me how to set your handler? or how to change the default handler?

Comment: check the url I've just inserted in my previous answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How can I do validation and find consumer from SAMLAssertion? I have SAML Assertion and from custom SP like spring WS I want to verify and get consumer.  Can I do this with OAuth2TokenValidationService interface. Please suggest if any examples related

Comment: check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031525/oauth-access-token-from-saml-response